# Is it possible to use alter table add column into two tables?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query for the 1st table.

```
$category=$_POST['category']; 
$sql = "ALTER TABLE men ADD $category INT BEFORE TOTAL";
```

This is my query for the 2nd table.

```
$category=$_POST['category'];
$sql = "ALTER TABLE women ADD $category INT BEFORE TOTAL";
```

The 1st query only works.

Comment: Did you got any error for second query?

Comment: Nope. It just won't add to my second table.

Comment: Can you please provide the code which will execute $sql query?

Comment: Does the second table also have a TOTAL field? Not sure what happens if you use BEFORE but the field doesnt exist.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Id DDL  .. you can't use the var for table or column name  ..but do the fatc you are using php ... you can use string concat  .. (be sure for proper content check for avoi sql injection

```
 $sql = "ALTER TABLE men
  ADD COLUMN  " . $category  . " INT BEFORE TOTAL";
```

and yes you can use alter table two or more time  ..but in separeated ..query or usinng multiquery function  ..

Comment: check for correct  space  between $category and  "  INT

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below code. Here I have modifed from your code.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost:3307";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "pageant"; //database 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); //open ng connection 
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $category=$_POST['category'];

 $sql = "ALTER TABLE men
  ADD " . $category  . " INT BEFORE TOTAL";

 $womenSql = "ALTER TABLE women
  ADD " . $category  . " INT BEFORE TOTAL";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE && $conn->query($womenSql) === TRUE ) {
    header('Location:welcome_admin.php');
     echo "New record created successfully";
    exit();


}else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost:3307";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "pageant"; //database 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); //open ng connection 
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $category=$_POST['category'];

 $sql = "ALTER TABLE men
  ADD " . $category  . " INT BEFORE TOTAL";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header('Location:welcome_admin.php');
     echo "New record created successfully";
    exit();


}else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}
$conn->close();
?>
<?php
$servername = "localhost:3307";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "pageant"; //database 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); //open ng connection 
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $category=$_POST['category'];

 $sql = "ALTER TABLE women
  ADD " . $category  . " INT BEFORE TOTAL";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header('Location:welcome_admin.php');
     echo "New record created successfully";
    exit();


}else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}
$conn->close();
?>

This is my code.
```

Comment: Once your first query executes and get succedd, you are calling exit(); function, So the code cannot able to execute further. Have modified your code below please check.

Comment: Thank you. I've already know what is the problem in my code. I remove the exit(); function .